# SQL syntax error with dynamically constructed INSERT?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax-error, sql-insert

I get the below error

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'c365online_script1.dbo.tProperty' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

The problem is with the statement that is dynamically constructed inside the two nested cursors  from what I gather it should look something like

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table(col1, col2, ...., colN) VALUES(Val1, val2, ...., ValN)
```

I am however unsure how I would construct the BELOW INSERT statement to resemble the above?.

```
EXEC('INSERT INTO ' + @Destination_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' SELECT * FROM ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' WHERE ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + '.CompanyID = ' + @Company_Id)
SET @Counter = 1 -- set the counter to make sure we execute loop only once.
END
```

Comment: Do you really need to insert identity field as well?

Comment: No I have taken it out now just the EXEC

Comment: Your example and executing code are two different things. You need to `use the column list` instead of `Select *`. Simply make your execution query like your example without identity column.

Comment: When you say Identity column do you mean @CompanyID

Comment: Use column names in your insert query !

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the list of columns because you don't insert into all of them (you don't insert into identity column). I'm guessing you're inserting from a table with the same structure from a different database - you need to specify all the source columns too in this case.

Your query will be (edit the column names):

```
EXEC('INSERT INTO ' + @Destination_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + '(col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + ' WHERE ' + @Source_Database_Name + '.dbo.' + @tablename + '.CompanyID = ' + @Company_Id)
```

Comment: What would i do if i wanted to select all tables from @source_ Database_Name, tProperty is just for testing

Comment: You mean including identity column?